# How Can I Get Values from Dialog in HTML and JavaScript, and Display it in PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a HTML `form` that contains `dialog`, and the `dialog` contains inputs
When user complete `dialog` inputs and click `send`, the values appear in the same page of `form` in `div`using JavaScript.

Then, when user complete other fields in form and click `submit`, user goes to another php page than contains entered values of all fields.

I want to get the values of dialog to php page

My form code:

```
<form id="form" action="message.php" method="POST" >
    
    <div class="container" id="executive-bodies-information">
        <!-- details-of-partners Dialog -->
        <dialog id="details-of-partners"> 
            <h2>بيانات الشركاء ، الملاك المستفيدون النهائيون ، المالكين المستفيدين</h2>
            <label for="details-of-partners-name">الاسم</label>
            <input type="text" id="details-of-partners-name" 
                    name="details-of-partners-name" placeholder="الاسم"  >

            <label for="details-of-partners-date-of-expiry">تاريخ الانتهاء</label>
            <input type="date" id="details-of-partners-date-of-expiry" 
                      name="details-of-partners-date-of-expiry" placeholder="تاريخ الانتهاء">



            <button button type="button" id="details-of-partners-send" >إرسال</button>
            <button button type="button" id="details-of-partners-cancel" 
                      onclick="closeDialog('details-of-partners')">إلغاء</button>
        
        </dialog>
        <!-- END details-of-partners Dialog -->
        
        <div>
            <button class="btn-add" type="button" onclick="showDialog('details-of-partners')">＋ جديد</button>
            <div id="details-of-partners-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label for="preferred-language">اللغة المفضلة</label>
        <select name="preferred-language" id="preferred-language" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>اختر</option>
            <option value="english">الانجليزية</option>
            <option value="arabic">العربية</option>
        </select>

    <div class="center">
        <button type="submit" id="submit"><h1>إرسـال</h1></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This button is clicked to show dialog:

[image]

This is the dialog:

[image]

Here is the result of dialog, while user enter new dialog with new values, a div is added with these new valaues in form page:

[image]

My JavaScript code to enable values to display in form page:

```
<script>
function showDialog(id) {
    var dialog= document.getElementById(id);
    dialog.show();
}

function closeDialog(id){
    var dialog= document.getElementById(id);
    dialog.close()
}

document.getElementById("details-of-partners-send").addEventListener('click', function(){
    var name= document.getElementById("details-of-partners-name").value;
    var date_of_expiry= document.getElementById("details-of-partners-date-of-expiry").value;
   

    document.getElementById("details-of-partners-container").innerHTML+= 
    `
    <div class="border" >
                <div class="details-box">
                    <span>الاسم: &emsp;</span>
                    <span>${ name}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="details-box">
                    <span>تاريخ الانتهاء: &emsp;</span>
                    <span> ${date_of_expiry}</span>
                </div>
    </div>
    `;
    closeDialog("details-of-partners");
})
</script>
```

An example of another code in `message.php` where I collect all values of form and `echo` values in it:

```
<span for="preferred-language">اللغة المفضلة: </span>
    <span><?php 
    if(isset($_POST['preferred-language'])){
        $lang= $_POST['preferred-language'];
        if($lang=="english"){
            echo "الانجليزية";
        }else{
            echo "العربية";
        }
    }
    ?> </span>
```

It will look like this:

[image]

And this is What I need, collect value from dialog using Javascript, then appears these values of div in php page
**Sorry for taking long time to explain it in details**

Comment: if the form is submitted and it seems you know '$_POST', what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: _"the values appear in the same page of form in divusing JavaScript."_ - divs and spans don't _submit_ anything. If you want to put data there that gets submitted together with the rest of the form fields ... then you need to put this into form fields as well.

Comment: @medelito  The issue is that user can use dialog many times to add different values before submit the form and show them at same time in form page, so when user submit form, how can I get these values? I want to collect all data and values in PHP page and I use $_POST to get values, but here I have an empty <div id="details-of-partners-container"></div> , that should PHP page check if this div has data, it will display it.

Comment: @CBroe please check my above comment and see if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest adding a hidden input where you can store the values from the dialogue so they can be submitted with the form, and since there can be multiple dialogues, you need an increment variable.

Before submit button : `<input type="hidden" name="increment" id="increment" />`

Outside of the onclick event: `var incrm = 1`

```
 document.getElementById("details-of-partners-container").innerHTML+= 
   ...
 <input type="hidden" name="name${incrm}" value="${name}" /> //close .innerHTML

 document.getElementById("increment").value = incrm;
 incrm++;
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand it and I tried your code, but I need to know what should I write in PHP page? I wrote ( echo (isset($_POST['name1']) ? $_POST['name1'] : 'nulll');  ) to test it, It works but it add only 1 value, also I tried to add name twice and it return the last name I've entered.

Should I loop in PHP and how?

Comment: Also, I tried to echo something like this: 
 echo  '
            <span>name: &emsp;</span>
            <span>' ; $_POST['details-of-partners-name']; '</span>
        ';
But it doesn't work and I think the problem is in $_POST

Comment: my code is just an example, you'll need to include the other values in your JS code, on PHP side you'll use the increment submitted to loop through all the values

Comment: So should I add hidden input for each value? like name and date ...etc

Comment: $_POST only works with Form Inputs. Yes, add a hidden input for each value

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll try it and I'll ask you if is there anything went wrong